# Was SVG(Scalable Vector Graphics) created with G-CODE in mind?

Tags: svg, g-code

As someone who has studied CNC (Computer Numerical Control), I was taught G-Code. When I opened an SVG file to apply certain compatibility changes to it, its path attribute reminded me of G-Code. Now, I get that both work with vectors and such, but is there any connection with the two?

Comment: I am talking about the path attribute. Considering the z-index having binary state, it can be represented in a 2D environment.